# Return the value of the cell one over to the right from found text

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to loop through a folder, find all workbooks which have the word "CUSTOMER ID" in them, and then copy from the adjacent cell (the customer's name one over to the right on the same row). The customer name is pasted into a master workbook along with workbook file names.

I found the following code, it returns the text I'm searching for.

```
Sub SearchFolders()
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim fld As Object
    Dim strSearch As String
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim wOut As Worksheet
    Dim wbk As Workbook
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim rFound As Range
    Dim strFirstAddress As String

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Change as desired
    strPath = "c:\MyFolder"
    strSearch = "Specific text"

    Set wOut = Worksheets.Add
    lRow = 1
    With wOut
        .Cells(lRow, 1) = "Workbook"
        .Cells(lRow, 2) = "Worksheet"
        .Cells(lRow, 3) = "Cell"
        .Cells(lRow, 4) = "Text in Cell"
        Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set fld = fso.GetFolder(strPath)

        strFile = Dir(strPath & "\*.xls*")
        Do While strFile <> ""
            Set wbk = Workbooks.Open _
              (Filename:=strPath & "\" & strFile, _
              UpdateLinks:=0, _
              ReadOnly:=True, _
              AddToMRU:=False)

            For Each wks In wbk.Worksheets
                Set rFound = wks.UsedRange.Find(strSearch)
                If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
                    strFirstAddress = rFound.Address
                End If
                Do
                    If rFound Is Nothing Then
                        Exit Do
                    Else
                        lRow = lRow + 1
                        .Cells(lRow, 1) = wbk.Name
                        .Cells(lRow, 2) = wks.Name
                        .Cells(lRow, 3) = rFound.Address
                        .Cells(lRow, 4) = rFound.Value
                    End If
                    Set rFound = wks.Cells.FindNext(After:=rFound)
                Loop While strFirstAddress <> rFound.Address
            Next

            wbk.Close (False)
            strFile = Dir
        Loop
        .Columns("A:D").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With
    MsgBox "Done"

ExitHandler:
    Set wOut = Nothing
    Set wks = Nothing
    Set wbk = Nothing
    Set fld = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation
    Resume ExitHandler
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

To return the value of the cell one over to the right from "Specific text":

```
.Cells(lRow, 4) = rFound.Offset(0, 1).Value
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the correct advice of @Tim Williams...

Find the block of code that looks like:

```
.Cells(lRow, 1) = wbk.Name
.Cells(lRow, 2) = wks.Name
.Cells(lRow, 3) = rFound.Address
.Cells(lRow, 4) = rFound.Value
```

And change the fourth line so it matches his code:

```
.Cells(lRow, 1) = wbk.Name
.Cells(lRow, 2) = wks.Name
.Cells(lRow, 3) = rFound.Address
.Cells(lRow, 4) = rFound.Offset(0, 1).Value
```

This is a handy piece of code to keep available in a toolkit but there are times when it's too heavy handed.  One example is creating a list of filenames and/or path strings.  If there's no need to open one file then it becomes laughingly absurd to open all of the files. Naturally this tool should be modified to better suit a variety of requirements but there's a better alternative for many scenarios.  If there's anyone out there with the daunting challenge of searching the contents of a thousand files, logging all files that generate positive hits,  and you don't need to open any of the files you've identified or care if a file has one or many positive hits... if that's you then the tool I recommend using that will outperform the one suggested here is called ..... Windows.

Windows must be configured to search file contents for this to work and the settings are in two different locations.  One is a checkbox in the Advanced Search drop drown menu of the Search window's Search Tab. The other is in the Search Tab of the Folder Options window.

Using the OP's example, to generate a list of all file names and locations containing the string "CUSTOMER ID". Simply open explorer, activate the search box, and type:

contents:CUSTOMER ID

When the search is complete, highlight the results you want to include in the list, shift right click in the highlighted area, select copy as path.  Paste your newly generated list into the application of your choice.  Yes, it really is that easy.